# Splitting a sentence using STRTOK in C

Tags: c, string, function, strtok

I`m having a hard time splitting a sentence read from a file in C programming language via **strtok** function. I scanned it from a file and stored it in a variable *info*, from which I need to separate words. I tried many things and eventually copied a code from the net and changed it a little bit. The code separates the first token nicely, but then it writes some nonsense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
//int i; //brojac
char info[]="";  // sve informacije, kasnije treba da bude u strukturi


FILE *pok;
pok=fopen("C:/Users/Trajkovici/Desktop/OsobeFajl.txt","r");
if(pok==NULL)
{
    printf("Greška prilikom otvaranja datoteke!");
}
fscanf(pok,"%[^\n]",&info);



puts("INFO: ");
puts(info);
//fclose(pok);

char * token = strtok(info, " ");
// loop through the string to extract all other tokens
while( token != NULL ) 
{
puts("\nTOKEN:");
printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
}
```

This is the file and the result:
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvwb1.png)
[The file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrCV0.png)
BTW, I wrote the same code, without extracting a sentence from a file, but instead declaring it manually. It works perfectly fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char string[] = "Sladjan Jankovic 46 Vranje";
   // Extract the first token
   puts(string);
   char * token = strtok(string, " ");
   // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
   while( token != NULL ) 
  {
  printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And this is the result of the above code:
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncLgm.png)
So, the problem is that I have two codes with literally same variables, but one of them splits into tokens fine, while the other one doesn`t. Any help about the first code?

P.S. Sorry for possible bad indentation, this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow. Also, some comments and lines from the file are in Serbian.

Comment: Please provide the result and the input data as text not images. Paste it directly into the question.

Comment: `char info[]=""` That's a one byte array. Not going to be able to store much there. Any code that tries to write more, like in the `fscanf`, results in undefined behaviour. Declare a larger array, e.g `char info[128];`

Comment: Also: Try to avoid `strtok()` It is close to unusable.

Comment: Thanks, I set the max size of the array to 100 (it doesn`t really matter) and it works now.

Comment: Not your main problem, but: most of the time, a good way to read a line of text is with `fgets`.  There's not usually a good reason to use `fscanf("%[^\n]")` like you did.  Among other things, `fgets` makes you tell it how big your input array is (so that it can promise not to overflow it), but this also helps remind you to allocate it big enough, which was your problem here.

Comment: @Boki I have in front of me a small box, a souvenir from a friend of mine, labeled "Mini šolja sa kašičicom u kutiji".  (Maybe that can be the next sentence you give to your program to split.)  I'm guessing one of those words means "mug", because that's what's in the box, a cute little mug with a scene from Belgrade on it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
char info[]="";
```

will allocate only one element. Using it in

```
fscanf(pok,"%[^\n]",&info);
```

is dangerous because it will write out-of-bounds when a string with positive length is read. (even one-character string is too long because there must be a terminating null-character).

Allocate enough elements like (for example):

```
char info[102400]="";
```

and specify the maximum length to read (the limit have to be at most the size of buffer minus one for terminating null-character) to prevent buffer overrun like this:

```
fscanf(pok,"%102399[^\n]",info);
```

Also note that you should remove `&` before `info`. Arrays in expressions (except for some exceptions) are automatically converted to pointers for their first elements. Adding `&` will have it pass a pointer to an array while `%[` expects a pointer to a character. Passing data having wrong type to `fscanf()` invokes *undefined behavior*.